# Linux with Altera DE2-115

Tags: linux, fpga, intel-fpga, nios

I'm trying to run Linux on my Altera DE2-115 FPGA according to [instructions](http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/Linux_with_MMU_on_VEEK/t-Pad#Unfortunately.2C_if_you_don.27t_have_VEEK.2Ft-PAD_kit.2C_but_you_have_DE2-115...). Obviously the first part works:

```
$ quartus_pgm -m jtag -c USB-Blaster[2-2] -o "p;tPad_Selector.sof"
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus Prime Programmer
    Info: Version 16.1.0 Build 196 10/24/2016 SJ Lite Edition
    Info: Copyright (C) 2016  Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
    Info: Your use of Intel Corporation's design tools, logic functions 
    Info: and other software and tools, and its AMPP partner logic 
    Info: functions, and any output files from any of the foregoing 
    Info: (including device programming or simulation files), and any 
    Info: associated documentation or information are expressly subject 
    Info: to the terms and conditions of the Intel Program License 
    Info: Subscription Agreement, the Intel Quartus Prime License Agreement,
    Info: the Intel MegaCore Function License Agreement, or other 
    Info: applicable license agreement, including, without limitation, 
    Info: that your use is for the sole purpose of programming logic 
    Info: devices manufactured by Intel and sold by Intel or its 
    Info: authorized distributors.  Please refer to the applicable 
    Info: agreement for further details.
    Info: Processing started: Mon Mar 13 17:10:04 2017
Info: Command: quartus_pgm -m jtag -c USB-Blaster[2-2] -o p;tPad_Selector.sof
Info (213045): Using programming cable "USB-Blaster [2-2]"
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 811: _dl_close: Assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!
Info (213011): Using programming file tPad_Selector.sof with checksum 0x00BBDF04 for device EP4CE115F29@1
Info (209060): Started Programmer operation at Mon Mar 13 17:10:05 2017
Info (209016): Configuring device index 1
Info (209017): Device 1 contains JTAG ID code 0x020F70DD
Info (209007): Configuration succeeded -- 1 device(s) configured
Info (209011): Successfully performed operation(s)
Info (209061): Ended Programmer operation at Mon Mar 13 17:10:11 2017
Info: Quartus Prime Programmer was successful. 0 errors, 0 warnings
    Info: Peak virtual memory: 453 megabytes
    Info: Processing ended: Mon Mar 13 17:10:11 2017
    Info: Elapsed time: 00:00:07
    Info: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
```

Then I get problems that I don't understand:

```
$ nios2-flash-programmer --epcs --base=0x0a001800 tPad_Selector.flash
Using cable "USB-Blaster [2-2]", device 1, instance 0x00
Resetting and pausing target processor: 
OK
No EPCS layout data - looking for section [EPCS-010216]
Unable to use EPCS device
Leaving target processor paused
```

I searched the Altera forums about it and couldn't understand. What is it that I'm supposed to do?

I've formatted the SD card with 3 partitions: ext3, fat and swap. Maybe the SD card is not compatible or what could it be?

The debug output:

```
$ nios2-flash-programmer --epcs --debug --base=0x0a001800 tPad_Selector.flash
Using cable "USB-Blaster [2-2]", device 1, instance 0x00
Resetting and pausing target processor: 
OK
Processor data bus width is 32 bits
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001800 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 0001703A 04C00074 9801483A 9CFFF804 1CE7FF8983FFD1E 0000203A
  Not here: reserved fields are non-zero
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001900 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 92400237 4A40100C 483FFD26 90000135 1CE7FF892400237 4A40200C
  Not here: reserved fields are non-zero
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001A00 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 108001C4 1004D0FA 002EE03A 003F9C06 1CE7FF8002EE03A 003F9506
  Not here: reserved fields are non-zero
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001B00 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 1CE7FF800000000 00000000
  Not here: SPI_SLAVE_SEL has 0 valid bits (should be between 1 and 16)
Looking for EPCS registers at address 0x0A001C00 (with 32bit alignment)
  Initial values: 00000000 00000000 00000260 00000000 1CE7FF800000000 00000001
  Valid registers found
EPCS signature is 0x16
EPCS identifier is 0x010216
No EPCS layout data - looking for section [EPCS-010216]
Unable to use EPCS device
Leaving target processor paused
```

Comment: Where did you try to run Linux? DE2-115 is EP4CE115 without hardcores... Your EPCS64 is EPCS64. What is your project? Can you start from booting nios without linux and running some simplest bare metal led blinking?

Comment: @osgx Yes, I can run pre-built project and even run uClinux built by somebody else who used Fedora. I'm also going to try to build with fedora instead of the ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instruction (which is not for DE2-115, but for another board) give directions for the error you got:

> ```
>  No EPCS layout data - looking for section [EPCS-010216] .
> ```

http://www.alterawiki.com/wiki/Linux_with_MMU_on_VEEK/t-Pad#Unfortunately.2C_if_you_don.27t_have_VEEK.2Ft-PAD_kit.2C_but_you_have_DE2-115...

> NOTE: When you execute the 'nios2-flash-programmer' command, you may get an error like
>      No EPCS layout data - looking for section [EPCS-010216] .
>   In such case, please refer the Altera forum page for the 'nios2-flash-programmer' or the section "A. Non-Standard Flash Memories" of "Nios II Flash Programmer User Guide" at pp.23.

Did you check "Nios II Flash Programmer User Guide"  https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_nios2_flash_programmer.pdf part [A. Non-Standard Flash Memories](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_nios2_flash_programmer.pdf#page=27)?

> To use the procedures in
>   this section, you need the data sheet for the flash memory device you are using. Make sure you fully
>   understand the CFI aspects of the device.
>   Some CFI flash memory devices contain missing or incorrect CFI table information. In such cases, the
>   Nios II Flash Programmer might fail based on the erroneous information in the CFI table. For these
>   devices, the Nios II Flash Programmer provides the following methods to override the CFI table and
>   successfully program flash memory ...
>   Always try using built-in recognition and
>   override before trying to create an override file. To determine whether the flash programmer recognizes
>   the device, **run the flash programmer from the command line with the `--debug` option**. If the flash
>   programmer overrides the CFI table, the flash programmer displays a message "Override data for this device is built in".

What are flash devices on original VEEK/T-pad & DE2-115 boards?

What does `nios2-flash-programmer --epcs --debug --base=0x0a001800 tPad_Selector.flash` command outputs?

Comment: @DjDac, There are some posts about "No EPCS Layout Data" on altera forums like  http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=24017. But I have no experience with `nios2-flash-programmer` tool and such error.